# How to fix: SSIS 2012 "Send EMail" task failing RFC5322?

Tags: ssis, email-validation

I noticed that SSIS 2012 generates a **Warning** that an address is invalid if the email address apparently is not in the recipient@domain.top_level_domain format. I need to be able to NOT generate a warning nor an error if the *recipient* (a.k.a., *localpart*) part, real and existing, is somewhat more complicated; for example, it includes more than one period and a plus sign (RFC5322 complaint but rare). **How do I handle or fix SSIS's issue with such addresses?**
Thanks for your looking at this question!
Kurt